# goswagger setting a reference for the field

Tags: go, reference, swagger, go-swagger, field-description

i have a hypothetical code

```
// swagger:model Type
// enum:none,offshore,international
type Type int

//swagger:model VatExemption
type Model struct {
    // The Model UUID.
    // Example - j290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
    // swagger:strfmt uuid
    ID uuid.UUID
    // swagger:refer Type
    Type Type
}
```

i used swagger: refer there (of course something like this not exist).
my question is do you know a way to tell the swagger that in the structure field to use the description from the indicated place